# Input type number translated

Tags: html

I'm building for mobile.

I have a form that includes an input type number. **When the device language is set to Arabic** whenever I set a value to this input it will show it in Arabic numbers.

If I do something like this:

document.getElementById('input-id').value = 444

In the UI, we can see the input will have a value of **٤٤٤**, this is the equivalent to 444 in Arabic numerals.

I don't have this issue in Input type="text" because it shows an String of characters so it doesn't convert them.

I know that I could use an Input type text instead but I would like to keep the consistency with the rest of my application and use an Input type number

I have this issue in **Chrome**, **Safari** and **Firefox**.

Clarification: I don't want it to translate it to Arabic Numerals. How can I make this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I don't want it to show Arabic Numerals.

Answer (score 6):

The HTML specification's [section on the Number `input` type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) states:

> **Note:** This specification does not define what user interface user agents are to use; user agent vendors are encouraged to consider what would best serve their users' needs. For example, **a user agent in Persian or Arabic markets might support Persian and Arabic numeric input (converting it to the format required for submission as described above)**. Similarly, a user agent designed for Romans might display the value in Roman numerals rather than in decimal; or (more realistically) a user agent designed for the French market might display the value with apostrophes between thousands and commas before the decimals, and allow the user to enter a value in that manner, internally converting it to the submission format described above.

This implies that it's down to the browser to determine what would "best serve their users' needs". I imagine the only way to override this would be by setting the language of your page to a language which does represent `٤٤٤` as `444` (such as English). To do this, we simply:

```
<body lang="en">
```

However, again, this is entirely down to the browser to decide whether to adhere to this.

Comment: Thank you, since Im not allowed to change the body lang ( because of other requirements) I think I will use an input type text.

Comment: Just to give you some feedback, I tried this and it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @DannySandi as I said it'd be down to the browser itself to conform. Might be worth finding the browser's bug tracker and reporting it as an issue.

Comment: Yeah I know, it makes the decision to convert the values based on the user agent language. So theres no way to change that. Just wanted to let you know the <body lang="en"> wouldn't fix the issue. And thank you sir.

Comment: HTML5 is clearly inclined into the idea of letter *user agent locale* be decisive, though it does not say this normatively. It does not forbid browsers from using *page locale* (as set by `lang` attribute), but neither does it encourage it, and browser vendors decided to use browser locales. This is one of fundamental flaws (or features) in HTML5 form field design.

Comment: but this may change the design

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the language attribute only for the desired input,
for example,

```html
<input type="number" lang="en">
```

Answer (score 0):

for all input that have text type
use jQuery Library

```
var arabics = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
var engs = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];


$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function (e) {

    var insideText = (e.key);
    var index = arabics.indexOf(insideText);
    if (index >= 0) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        value.substr(0, value.length - 1) != null ? value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1) + engs[index] : value = engs[index];
        $(this).val(value);
    }


});
```