# Localization of input for numbers

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I started to translate English web site to other languages. Thai, Bengali...

For example Bengali language. 
To get a number from JavaScript I'm doing something like that:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" id="demoin" lang="bn"></input>
<script>
    var a = 12345.44;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (a.toLocaleString('bn-US'));
    document.getElementById("demoin").value = a.toLocaleString('bn-US');
</script>
```

And I'm getting this, as expected.

> ১২,৩৪৫.৪৪

But how can I deal with `<input type="number">` elements.
Browser does not accept Bengali numbers in these inputs.

If I use `type="text"` I'm getting Bengali numbers on the Server and my PHP needed to convert it to put in into MySQL database.

How do other developers deal with translations? 
Is there a JS library or Browser settings to help with it?

Comment: Should that not be bn-BD?

Comment: I found this interesting: https://www.w3.org/International/tests/test-incubator/locales-in-forms/numbers.html

Comment: The country only matters if the language is used by multiple countries and each country has their official rules.

Comment: I think this is a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217604/input-type-number-translated# and I did not see my EN windows enter BN numbers when setting the language on the number fields to bn

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev: not really, the country matter. Locales have always the country component (because currency is also part of locale definition). Do not assume browsers and OS will pick a good locale (and country) for a defined language. Less used locales are not very well reviewed. [This is not much relevant to your question, but you should be aware of this, so your last comment could lead to wrong conclusions]